Std-err log files are not getting generated in tomcat for SLES. How to generate std-err log files?
Std-err log files are not getting generated in tomcat for SLES.
In windows i am able to see std-err log file, but SLES i cant see one. Is there a specific procedure that we must follow to enable std-err log from server side , Please specify the workflow. I dowbloaded the tar.gz version to install apache tomcat for SLES.
Apacge tomcat version: 9.0.16
